# How to pair bluetooth devices programatically without user interaction?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I know there are many such questions on SO but none of them has been able to address my issue.I am trying to implement a Bluetooth pairing programatically  between two devices. I am able to pair devices but the problem is that it requires user to press pair button which I don't want in my app. I want them to get connected without any user interaction or if that is  not possible it should ask only one device to press the pair button and should get paired. I have a Samsung TV that works in a way that when I try to connect my android phone's Bluetooth with it..A pair pin request pops up on my phone and when I hit pair it gets paired it doesn't show any thing on TV and still they both get paired. I need to implement this in my app. I have tried this code but it doesnot take the password and get connected it still asks for the password.

```
public void setBluetoothPairingPin(BluetoothDevice device)
{
    byte[] pinBytes = convertPinToBytes("0000");
    try {
          Log.d(TAG, "Try to set the PIN");
          Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("setPin", byte[].class);
          m.invoke(device, pinBytes);
          Log.d(TAG, "Success to add the PIN.");
          try {
                device.getClass().getMethod("setPairingConfirmation", boolean.class).invoke(device, true);
                Log.d(TAG, "Success to setPairingConfirmation.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

I have been searching for a solution for almost a week now.Any ideas/suggestions to achieve the above will be really appreciated.

Comment: have you got the solution, i have same scenario with mobile and car and i don't want pairing popup to show up in my device, because my application is device owner with kiosk mode which will not allow pairing popup to show up.

Answer (score 5):

You should be try this...!

```
private void pairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
            try {
                Method method = device.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
                method.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

and

```
mAdapter.setData(mDeviceList);
        mAdapter.setListener(new DeviceListAdapter.OnPairButtonClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onPairButtonClick(int position) {               
                BluetoothDevice device = mDeviceList.get(position);

                if (device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    unpairDevice(device);
                } else {
                    showToast("Pairing...");
                    pairDevice(device);//here is calling
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code on while pair button clicked:

```java
    String strPsw = "FBK645NKL"
    mAdapter.setData(mDeviceList);
    mAdapter.setListener(new OnPairButtonClickListener() {
    
                @Override
                public void onPairButtonClick(int position) {
                    BluetoothDevice device = mDeviceList.get(position);
    
                    if (device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                        unpairDevice(device);
                    }  else {
                        Log.d("mylog", "HAS BOND_BONDED");
                        try {
                            ClsUtils.createBond(device.getClass(), device);
                            ClsUtils.setPin(device.getClass(), device, strPsw); //
                            ClsUtils.createBond(device.getClass(), device);
    //                      remoteDevice = device; // ?remoteDevice
                            result = true;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            Log.d("mylog", "setPiN failed!");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    return;
                }
    
            });
```

And you must write a code for ClsUtils.java:

```java
    //ClsUtils code for Bluetooth Device Pairing and Bonding...
    
    import java.lang.reflect.Field;
    import java.lang.reflect.Method;
    
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
    import android.util.Log;
    
    public class ClsUtils {
    
        /**
         * ?platform/packages/apps/Settings.git
         * /Settings/src/com/android/settings/bluetooth/CachedBluetoothDevice.java
         */
        @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
        static public boolean createBond(Class btClass, BluetoothDevice btDevice)
                throws Exception {
            Method createBondMethod = btClass.getMethod("createBond");
            Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) createBondMethod.invoke(btDevice);
            return returnValue.booleanValue();
        }
    
        /**
         * ?platform/packages/apps/Settings.git
         * /Settings/src/com/android/settings/bluetooth/CachedBluetoothDevice.java
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        static public boolean removeBond(Class btClass, BluetoothDevice btDevice)
                throws Exception {
            Method removeBondMethod = btClass.getMethod("removeBond");
            Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) removeBondMethod.invoke(btDevice);
            return returnValue.booleanValue();
        }
    
        @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
        static public boolean setPin(Class btClass, BluetoothDevice btDevice,
                String str) throws Exception {
            try {
                Method removeBondMethod = btClass.getDeclaredMethod("setPin",
                        new Class[] { byte[].class });
                Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) removeBondMethod.invoke(btDevice,
                        new Object[] { str.getBytes() });
                Log.e("returnValue", "" + returnValue);
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
    
        }
    
        //
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        static public boolean cancelPairingUserInput(Class btClass,
                BluetoothDevice device)
    
        throws Exception {
            Method createBondMethod = btClass.getMethod("cancelPairingUserInput");
            // cancelBondProcess()
            Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) createBondMethod.invoke(device);
            return returnValue.booleanValue();
        }
    
        //
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        static public boolean cancelBondProcess(Class btClass,
                BluetoothDevice device)
    
        throws Exception {
            Method createBondMethod = btClass.getMethod("cancelBondProcess");
            Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) createBondMethod.invoke(device);
            return returnValue.booleanValue();
        }
    
        /**
         *
         * @param clsShow
         */
        static public void printAllInform(Class clsShow) {
            try {
                //
                Method[] hideMethod = clsShow.getMethods();
                int i = 0;
                for (; i < hideMethod.length; i++) {
                    Log.e("method name", hideMethod[i].getName() + ";and the i is:"
                            + i);
                }
                //
                Field[] allFields = clsShow.getFields();
                for (i = 0; i < allFields.length; i++) {
                    Log.e("Field name", allFields[i].getName());
                }
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    
    
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            static public boolean autoBond(Class btClass,BluetoothDevice device,String strPin) throws Exception {   
            
            Method autoBondMethod = btClass.getMethod("setPin",
                    new Class[] { byte[].class });
            Boolean result = (Boolean) autoBondMethod.invoke(device,
                    new Object[] { strPin.getBytes() });
            return result;
    
        }
    
    }
```

This code is useful for automatically pairing and connecting Bluetooth devices without user-interaction.

Comment: It works without user interaction. But still the pop up appears for a second. Is there any way by which we can avoid the pop up visibility ?